# SpringBoot Container in Junit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I am unable to understand few things while testing with JUnit, I have written a few tests, while some seem to work simply with

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

and

```
@Mock
```

some seem not to work with them, and so I have to use

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

and

```
@MockBean
```

I understand that @MockBean is used when dealing with Spring Container, while @Mock is just to use to replicate/mock a certain class and its methods. But what would be the perfect time to use @MockBean?

```
@Test
    public void addBulkFcmLog() throws Exception {
        JacksonTester.initFields(this, new ObjectMapper());
        AdminFcmResource adminFcmResource = AdminFcmResource.builder()
                .adminId(123L)
                .build();

        given(this.fcmService.addBulkFcmLog(any(BulkFcmDataResource.class))).willReturn(adminFcmResource);

        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(
                post(Routes.SEND_FCM + "/admin/logs/add")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(bulkFcmDataResourceJacksonTester.write(BulkFcmDataResource.builder().adminId(123L).build()).getJson()))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse();

        assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(
                adminFcmResourceJacksonTester.write(adminFcmResource).getJson()
        );
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED.value());

    }
```

Above is a test I wrote for a controller in my spring boot application, but When i mock the fcmService class using @Mock, the response comes with an empty body, but then I changed It to @MockBean and Autowired the controller class then test returned the right result.
How did this happen?

Comment: I used annotate the service with @MockBean and using TestRestTemplate to test the controller.

Answer (score 1):

In an integration-test context it is always advisable to work with beans (mocked if necessary). Few points to keep in mind:

- `@MockBean` takes care of injecting the object, you do not need to set it yourself.
- If your configuration is wrong (you did not specify a `@Qualifier` for example), the test will expose that problem on startup.
- In an integration test you want to have your system in a state which resembles the prod scenario as close as possible, and `@MockBean` gets you closer than a plain `@Mock`
- Many times the bean dependencies have no `setters` and manual injection would be just plain hard.

Comment: I'm just trying to do a unit test, so shouldn't a plain mock suffice, plus i mocked the service, so why isnt the mocked object returning the object in my willReturn